Http Post Request Causes Internal Server error only when coming from Salesforce
I am attempting to use an external api to convert from html to markdown. I have an apex class that is called in a flow that makes the request and returns the response as a variable. When sent from Salesforce the request causes an internal server error from the api. When sent through curl or postman the request is successful. Here is the apex class I have been using.
public with sharing class HtmlToMarkdownConverter {
    // Invocable method to be called from a Salesforce Flow
    @InvocableMethod(label='Convert HTML to Markdown' description='Converts HTML to Markdown using an external API')
    public static List<APIResponse> convertHtmlToMarkdown(List<RequestWrapper> request) {
        // List to store the API responses
        List<APIResponse> responses = new List<APIResponse>();

        for(RequestWrapper req : request) {
            try {
                // Setup the HTTP request
                HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
                String endpoint = 'callout:html_to_markdown_named/v1/convert';
                httpRequest.setEndpoint(endpoint);
                httpRequest.setMethod('POST');
                httpRequest.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                
                // Create a map to hold the JSON structure
                Map<String, String> requestBodyMap = new Map<String, String>();
                requestBodyMap.put('html', req.html);

                // Serialize the map to a JSON string
                String requestBody = JSON.serialize(requestBodyMap);
                httpRequest.setBody(requestBody);
                
                // Send the request
                Http http = new Http();
                HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(httpRequest);

                // Create an APIResponse object for the current request
                APIResponse apiResponse = new APIResponse();
                apiResponse.requestBody = requestBody; // Store the request body

                // Check the response status and process the response
                if (httpResponse.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                    // Parse the response body and extract the markdown field
                    String responseBody = httpResponse.getBody();
                    Map<String, Object> jsonResponse = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(responseBody);
                    String markdown = (String) jsonResponse.get('markdown');

                    // Add the markdown response to the API response
                    apiResponse.markdown = markdown;
                } else {
                    // Handle non-200 responses
                    apiResponse.markdown = 'Error: ' + httpResponse.getBody();
                }

                responses.add(apiResponse); // Add the response to the list

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Handle exceptions and log the error
                APIResponse errorResponse = new APIResponse();
                errorResponse.markdown = 'Exception: ' + e.getMessage();
                responses.add(errorResponse);
            }
        }

        // Return the API responses
        return responses;
    }

    // Wrapper class for the input HTML string
    public class RequestWrapper {
        @InvocableVariable(required=true description='HTML string to convert')
        public String html;
    }

    // Wrapper class for the API response
    public class APIResponse {
        @InvocableVariable(description='Converted Markdown Text')
        public String markdown;
        
        @InvocableVariable(description='JSON request body sent to the API')
        public String requestBody; // New field to store the serialized request body
    }
}

The authentication uses an api key in a named/ external credential. I am running this as sys admin and have permission for the external credential. I also added the base url for the endpoint as a trusted url.
I have been able to trigger other errors by sending incorrect headers or editing the key. I have also tried hard coding the endpoint, api key etc into the apex class and get the same error.
I am pretty new to Salesforce and I am not sure what would cause this.
Also, here is the link to the api documentation: https://html-to-markdown.com/api

Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful. What you have is sufficiently Minimal, not Complete, and therefore not Reproducible.

Probably the first thing to look at is to system.debug(requestBody); So you can see if there's any double-serialization or if the html you're sending has been "escaped" (e.g. <div>hello world</div> would become &lt;div&gt;hello world&lt;/div&gt;)

The json and html both look valid, we ended up switching to a different API and did not run into the same issue. Thanks for your reply!
